# Subset sum using recursive backtracking in python using list and return statements.

Tags: recursion, backtracking, subset-sum

I am trying to solve the subset sum problem using recursive back-tracking. While it works if I print the result instantly, it does not seem to work if I try to return it.
Here is a look at the code in python. I have added intermediate print statements to make things easier(please uncomment them):

```
l = [int(i) for i in input().split()]
num = int(input())
#print(num)
#print(l)
def subset(l):
    tot = 0
    ch = []
    return(subsetHelper(l,tot,num,ch))
def subsetHelper(l,tot,num,ch):
    #print("("+str(l)+" "+str(tot)+" "+str(num)+" "+str(ch)+")")
    if(tot==num):
        return(ch)
    elif(tot>num or len(l)==0):
        return
    else:
        ch.append(l[0])
        return subsetHelper(l[1:],tot+l[0],num,ch)
        del ch[-1]
        return subsetHelper(l[1:],tot,num,ch)
print(subset(l))
```

The same concept works when I print the result without returning it.

```
l = [int(i) for i in input().split()]
num = int(input())
#print(num)
#print(l)
def subset(l):
    tot = 0
    ch = []
    subsetHelper(l,tot,num,ch)
def subsetHelper(l,tot,num,ch):
    #print("("+str(l)+" "+str(tot)+" "+str(num)+" "+str(ch)+")")
    if(tot==num):
        print(ch)
    elif(tot>num or len(l)==0):
        #return "Hello"
        return
    else:
        ch.append(l[0])
        subsetHelper(l[1:],tot+l[0],num,ch)
        del ch[-1]
        subsetHelper(l[1:],tot,num,ch)
subset(l)
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: What does the input and expected output look like? Can you specifically describe "subset sum"? Is it https://www.reddit.com/r/dailyprogrammer/comments/68oda5/20170501_challenge_313_easy_subset_sum/?

Comment: The input would be a list, say "l"  and a number, say "num" and the output would be a subset of the given input say "l1" such that the numbers of l1 add up to the num
For example -
Input - [1,3,7,2,4], 6
Output - [1,3,2]
Explanation - 1+3+2 = 6
Although there might be multiple solutions for this ( [2,4] is also a valid solution), I want the function to return a single solution instead of printing all possible solutions.